# How to invoke a method which throws an Exception using Java Reflection?

Tags: java, exception, reflection, invoke

I would like to invoke a method, using Java Reflection.

The problem is that this method (which I wrote) throws an Exception (I created a *myCustomException*). When I add a try/catch clause, I can't run my project, because Eclipse says "the catch clause is unreachable".

Here is when I try to invoke *myMethod* in the class *MyClass* :

```
270.    myMethod.invoke(null, myParam); // NB : null because myMethod is static
```

When *myMethod* does not throw a *MyCustomException*, eveything is fine. But when it throws a *MyCustomException*, I get this error message :

Let's say I try to invoke *fooMethod()*, which is in the class *BarClass()*, and  :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.tests.MyClass.test5(270)
    at com.tests.MyClass.main(297)
Caused by: com.tests.MyCustomException
    at com.tests.barClass.fooMethod(BarClass.java:129)
    ... 6 more
```

Is it even possible ? Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: It looks like the method invocation is throwing an Exception. Surround it with try-catch.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can get the cause of it that would be the original exception.

```
InvocationTargetException.getCause();
```

From documentation:

> InvocationTargetException is a checked exception that wraps an
>   exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html

In your catch block, you could check if exception is from the type you expect and handle it.

One simple approach would be:

```
try {
   ...
} catch (InvocationTargetException ite) {
   if (ite.getCause() instanceof SomeExceptionType) {
      ...
   } else {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works. But I can't get the message from my MyCustomException, with `getCause().getMessage()`, even if I created my MyCustomException like this : `new MyCustomException("the message")`.

Comment: I think this could be due your specific implementation, could you debug and check if the exception is really holding the message?

Comment: I succeeded with Marko Topolnik 's way. Thank you anyway.

Comment: OP, Francisco's approach and mine are equivalent and should either both give you the message, or none, depending on factors not related to the code we are showing. The only advantage of my approach is not having to go through the if-else parade.

Comment: Actually it didn't work either ! I only get `null`when I do `getMessage()`, which is strange because the same class works perfectly in an other context without reflection.

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault ! You'll see my error quickly, here was my constructor :

`public FormulaireException(String string) {
  super();
 }`. `I should have done :super(string);`

Answer (score 10):

One way to do it:

```
try { myMethod.invoke(null, myParam); }
catch (InvocationTargetException e) { 
  try { throw e.getCause(); }
  catch (MyCustomException e) { ...}
  catch (MyOtherException e) { ...}
}
```

Comment: It works. It was my fault, in my MyCustomException, the constructor was not set correctly : I didn't pass the message ! Stupid error

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add a `catch` clause in the method that executes `myMethod.invoke(null, myParam)`, then that's obviously not the right way of doing it. In this case you're invoking the method via reflection and this is not the place to be catching the exception, as the `invoke` method throws other exceptions. Once you invoke the method that throws the exception, if there is an exception, it will get thrown and wrapped in an `InvocationTargetException`, if I recall correctly.

Check the last part of [this explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodTrouble.html) concerning the `InvocationTargetException`.