# Catch specific exception in java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Given a class with static method and throw some exception

```
class Foo {
    public static void doThis() throws CannotDoThisException {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I am using the following reflection to invoke the doThis method

```
public class Bar {
    Class c = Class.forName("Foo");
    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("doThis",null);
    try {
        m.invoke(null,null);
    } catch (CannotDoThisException e) {
       //Compiler says this is unreachable block.
    }
}
```

How can I catch the exception CannotDoThisException?

Comment: InvokeTargetException (or something like that) wraps invoked method exceptions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11452061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't catch that exception is that `Method::invoke` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-)) won't throw it !

If the method that you are calling via `invoke` throws *any* exception, the reflection layer catches it and then creates and throws an `InvocationTargetException` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html)) with the original exception as the exception's `cause`.

So this is what you need to do:

```
public class Bar {
    Class c = Class.forName("Foo");
    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("doThis",null);
    try {
        m.invoke(null,null);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
       if (e.getCause() instanceof CannotDoThisException) {
           // do something about it
       } else {
           // do something else
           // if the `cause` exception is unchecked you could rethrow it.
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer! I searched but couldn't find it. Without knowing the keyword of InvocationTargetException, it is kind of difficult to find the duplicates. Also thanks to Dave pointing out the duplicate.